# Creating limited links in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I create dynamic links with expiration time in asp.net?

I've thought about it and I think I should do it through a handler and giving handler url instead of real url.

I think I should make a random string and in query ask for that random string from user to confirm and returning file in `Response.WriteBinary`. But I really don't know how to do so.

Comment: I suggest you put some code with this question; otherwise it will get closed as you are asking someone to do all of the work for you. This is a question and answer site geared towards helping people getting their existing code to work, not a list your requirements and have someone gift you the solution.

Comment: You probably tried a lot of thing to get to this question... Assuming you are already come up with `sample.com/timedlink?start=2015-05-01&end=2015-05-13&userid=123456&fileId=54321&speedRating=blazingFast` it is not clear what concrete problems you have (also make sure to ask *single* concrete question in one post).

Comment: @KarlAnderson It's not that I'm lazy and I have made a checklist and put it here and expecting others to give me answers as gifts. What I want can be very common. But implementing them is hard and I really don't have a clue how to implement. I've asked this question after days of searching and testing and THINKING. This question can be a very common question among new asp.net developers. Anyway thank you for reading my question and trying to help me. I have edited it to be less broad

Answer (score 1):

You can encode a validity period in the link you give out.  Encrypt that time period (e.g. with AES, then encoded in BASE64 to ensure that part of the URL contains only valid characters).

Decrypt the validity period on the server.  If the current time matches the valid time, stream the actual file (don't redirect, or you expose the real URL).

To add a download speed limit, [have a look at this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETLimitDownloadSpeed-819f5d04).

> This project illustrates how to limit the download speed via coding.
>
> Please kindly note that IIS7 has an extension called Bit Rate Throttling can
> do this feature for us with very simple option settings. For more info about
> Bit Rate Throttling, please refer to: http://www.iis.net/download/BitRateThrottling